# finding the min and max element in vector using std::min_element, std::max_element

Tags: c++, stl

I am new to C++, and I am trying to find the minimum and maximum elements of a `std::vector`, but both `std::min_element()` and `std::max_element()` are not working together. The given output is only the minimum value.  In the output, only the minimum value is printed twice, instead of minimum first then maximum.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm> 
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool comp1_(int a, int b) 
{ 
    return a > b; 
}

bool comp2(int a, int b) 
{ 
    return a < b; 
}

int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> myvector;
    vector<int>::iterator i1;
    vector<int>::iterator i2;
    int n, num;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> num;
        myvector.push_back(num);
    }
    i2 = std::min_element(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), comp2);
    cout << *i2 << " ";
    i1 = std::max_element(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), comp1_); 
    cout << *i1; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) is probably what you want.

Comment: Your comparer for `max_element` is returning the wrong value. [From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element): "*... returns ​`true` if **the first argument is less than the second**.*" Your comparer is doing the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i1 = std::max_element(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), comp1_);
```

is wrong

```
i1 = std::max_element(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), comp2);
```

would work.

By using `comp1_` with `max_element` you are effectively asking for the minimum element because max_element finds the element x for which comp1_(x, y) is not true for any y.

You've effectively done a double negative, you've switched to asking for the maximum element but by also reversing the comparison function you've switched to asking for the minimum again.

What you should do when using `min_element` and `max_element` is pass a comparison function that means 'less than', then these functions will do what they say.

You might now realise that

```
i2 = std::min_element(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), comp1_);
```

would get you the maximum element.

Comment: You may want to mention [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) since OP is looking for *both* min and max.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is simply that you use `max_element` incorrectly. It expects a comparison which returns ​true if the first argument is less than the second. You will need to use `comp2_` in both cases. So in your program it should read

```
i1 = std::max_element(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), comp2);
```

**The best practice to achieve what you want** is using `minmax_element` like Jesper mentioned

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm> 
#include <vector>


bool compLess(int a, int b)
{
    return (a < b);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<int> myvector;

    int n, num;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> num;
        myvector.push_back(num);
    }

    auto minmax = std::minmax_element(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), compLess);
    cout << "min: " << *minmax.first << "\tmax:" << *minmax.second << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

With this you do not have to iterate twice through the array.

**Hint** Do not use `using namespace std;` in global namespace. I would consider that to be bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use comp2 as well for the call of std::max_element. The comparison operator is for both min_element and max_element the same.

Alternatively you could also use 
    `i1 = std::min_element(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), comp1_);`

Check out also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element.